# Perl to sort words by user-defined alphabet sequence

Tags: perl, sorting

I have an array of "words" (strings), which consist of letters from an "alphabet" with user-defined sequence. E.g my "alphabet" starts with `"ʔ ʕ b g d"`, so a list of "words" `(bʔd ʔbg ʕʔb bʕd)` after `sort by_my_alphabet` should be `ʔbd ʕʔb bʔd bʕd`.

```
sort by_my_alphabet (bʔd ʔbg ʕʔb bʕd) # gives ʔbd ʕʔb bʔd bʕd
```

Is there a way to make a simple subroutine `by_my_alphabet` with `$a` and `$b` to solve this problem?

Comment: Your code above is correct, you just need to implement by_my_alphabet. Check out the examples here which demonstrate using a custom comparator: https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html

Answer (score 4):

Simple, and very fast because it doesn't use a compare callback, but it needs to scan the entire string:

```
use utf8;

my @my_chr = split //, "ʔʕbgd";
my %my_ord = map { $my_chr[$_] => $_ } 0..$#my_chr;

my @sorted =
   map { join '', @my_chr[ unpack 'W*', $_ ] }   # "\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04" ⇒ "ʔʕbgd"
   sort
   map { pack 'W*', @my_ord{ split //, $_ } }    # "ʔʕbgd" ⇒ "\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04"
   @unsorted;
```

Optimized for long strings since it only scans a string up until a difference is found:

```
use utf8;

use List::Util qw( min );

my @my_chr = split //, "ʔʕbgd";
my %my_ord = map { $my_chr[$_] => $_ } 0..$#my_chr;

sub my_cmp($$) {
   for ( 0 .. ( min map length($_), @_ ) - 1 ) {
      my $cmp = $my_ord{substr($_[0], $_, 1)} <=> $my_ord{substr($_[1], $_, 1)};
      return $cmp if $cmp;
   }

   return length($_[0]) <=> length($_[1]);
}

my @sorted = sort my_cmp @unsorted;
```

Both should be faster than [Sobrique's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46452567/589924). Theirs uses a compare callback, and it scans the entire strings being compared.

Comment: Great! Though I'm only a beginner in Perl, so I don't understand how `map`, `$$`, and `min map` work. Hope to learn all of it soon and fully understand the code.

Comment: `$$` is a prototype expected for functions called by `sort func LIST`. It effectively means the sub takes two parameters. (generally speaking, avoid sub prototypes!)

Comment: `min` is a sub that returns the smallest of the numbers passed as arguments.

Comment: `map` applies a transformation to the each value passed to it. e.g. `map { uc($_) } "abc", "def"` is equivalent to `uc("abc"), uc("def")`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

`sort` can take any function that returns a relative sort position. All you need is a function that correctly looks up the 'sort value' of a string for comparing.

So all you need to do here is define a 'relative weight' of your extra letters, and then compare the two.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings; 

use Data::Dumper;

my @sort_order = qw ( B C A D ); 

my @array_to_sort = qw ( A B C D A B C D AB BB CCC ABC ); 

my $count = 0; 
my %position_of;
$position_of{$_} = $count++ for @sort_order;

print Dumper \%position_of;

sub sort_by_pos {

   my @a = split //, $a;
   my @b = split //, $b; 

   #iterate one letter at a time, using 'shift' to take it off the front
   #of the array.
   while ( @a and @b ) {
     my $result = $position_of{shift @a} <=> $position_of{shift @b};
     #result is 'true' if it's "-1" or "1" which indicates relative position.
     # 0 is false, and that'll cause the next loop iteration to test the next
     #letter-pair
     return $result if $result;
   }
   #return a value based on remaining length - longest 'string' will sort last;
   #That's so "AAA" comparing with "AA" comparison actually work, 
   return scalar @a <=> scalar @b;
}


my @new = sort { sort_by_pos } @array_to_sort;

print Dumper \@new;
```

Bit of a simple case, but it sorts our array into:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'B',
          'B',
          'BB',
          'C',
          'C',
          'CCC',
          'A',
          'A',
          'AB',
          'ABC',
          'D',
          'D'
        ];
```